# So when I run my python selenium script through jenkins, how should I write the 'driver = webdriver.Chrome()'?

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins, webdriver

So when I run my python selenium script through Jenkins, how should I write the `driver = webdriver.Chrome()`

How should I put the chrome webdriver EXE in jenkins?

Where should I put it?

Comment: Did you try anything that fails, if so let us know, we'd be happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have added your repository path in jenkins during job configuration, Jenkins will create a virtual copy of your workspace. So, as long as the webdriver file is somewhere in your project folder structure and as long as you are using relative path to reference it in your code, there shouldn't be any issues with respect to driver in invocation.

You question also depends on several params like:
1. Whether you are using Maven to run the test
2. Whether you are running tests on Jenkins locally or on a remote machine using Selenium Grid Architecture.